# How to apply different method parameters for different columns in pandas fillna() method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a data frame like this.

```
Name    Roll    GPA
A       10      5.0
B       NaN     4.5
C       12      NaN
```

I am using:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

But it fills all the columns using `ffill` method.

But I want to fill the `NaN` value using both `ffill` & `bfill` method. For example, I want to apply `method='ffill'` to the **Roll** column and `method='bfill'` to the **GPA** column. How can I do this?

Comment: `df2 = df.assign(Roll=df.Roll.ffill(), GPA=df.GPA.bfill())`

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed. It works. Please add this as an answer so that I can mark as best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do both.

```
df2 = df.assign(Roll=df.Roll.ffill(), GPA=df.GPA.bfill())
```